# ng-model does not work after drag and drop with connectToSortable option

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive, drag-and-drop

I use directives to use draggable/sortable from jquery-ui. Goal is to allow user to drag object from one area to another. Draggable element contains piece of angular code.

The issue is, that after moving element to another DOM element, change of 
`<select>` tag does not update the `ng-model` attribute.

After dropping element that contains select into droppable area it stops updating string `align="{{align}}"` with the new value of select once changed.

```
    <div class="" data-drag="true" data-jqyoui-options='{connectToSortable: ".my-sortable"}' jqyoui-draggable="{animate:true}" >
      haha
      <select ng-model="align">
        <option value="1">1
        <option value="2">2
      </select>
      align="{{align}}"
    </div>

    <br/><br/><br/>

    <div class="thumbnail my-sortable" ui-sortable data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options jqyoui-droppable style='height:50px;'>
    </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/18NQiCNRQLEuRpSCpEIq?p=preview

Comment: When I drag the element which includes select tag to div.thumbnail in your Plunker, I got some jquery-ui error in console log.
On the other hand, when I drag to other area(except div.thumbnail), it seems to work fine.
Judging from this situation, I think this seems to be jquery-ui problem.